# Can two machines on VPN connect to each other

Tags: networking, vpn

We have our Middleware server which is connected to client network through VPN.

Now we need to connect to this server.
My question is if we connect our development systems to client network using VPN, will we be able to access the server, which should be theoratically.

Also will this be the best solution or we can do something better?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things at play here but in theory yes, if you connect over VPN to the same end network you should be able to access the resources on that network based on the rules the VPN/Firewall server has in place.

Why didn't you just test it out?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly.  Yes, if you VPN into your client network you should be able to access their network and the middleware server, since they are able to access the middleware server.

If the client can VPN into their own network from home and access the middleware server, then you should be able to do the same thing with them once setup on their VPN.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

Since you haven't mentioned which VPN solution you are using, i can just guess, but you should siable client isolation, and check any potential firewall rules, to allow traffic between them